# How to create a mixin for `django_filters.FilterSet`?

Tags: python, django

I have a bunch of `FilterSet`s to which I'd like to add the same new filters, but whenever I do something like below, I get an error saying that `FilterSet.Meta` must specify a model. E.G:

```py
class ModifiedAtMixin:
   modified_at_until = django_filters.DateTimeFilter(method="modified_until")

   def modified_until(self, queryset, name, value):
      return queryset.filter(modified_at__lte=value)

   class Meta:
      fields = ("modified_at_until",)
   

class FooFilterSet(ModifiedAtMixin, django_filters.rest_framework.FilterSet):
   created_at_until = django_filters.DateTimeFilter(method="created_until")

   def created_until(self, queryset, name, value):
      return queryset.filter(created_at__lte=value)

   class Meta:
      model = Foo
      fields = ModifiedAtMixin.Meta.fields + ("created_at_until",)
```

For reference, I also tried changing the order of parent classes in `FooFilterSet` and got nothing.

How can I created a reusable mixin such as `ModifiedAtMixin`

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the design of FilterSet is such that you have to apply a hacky solution:

```
class ModifiedAtMixin:
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        new_obj = super().__new__(cls)
        filter_ = django_filters.DateTimeFilter(method="created_until", field_name="modified_at_until")
        new_obj.base_filters.update({"modified_at_until": filter_})
        return new_obj

   def modified_until(self, queryset, name, value):
      return queryset.filter(modified_at__lte=value)
```